# Rotation invariance of an integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, special-functions, specific-calculation

Consider the integral depending on 2 parameters
$$f(\tau,x):=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dp}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}e^{-\sqrt{p^2+1}\tau+ipx},$$
where $\tau >0,x\in \mathbb{R}$. This integral absolutely converges in this region.

**Question. Is it true that $f(\tau,x)$ is $SO(2)$ invariant in the above region, i.e. depends only on $\tau^2+x^2$?**

Remark. My motivation to ask this question comes from the well known fact that after the so called Wick rotation $\tau=it$  one gets an integral invariant under the Lorentz transformations in the plane $(t,x)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Denote $p=\sinh s$, then $s\in (-\infty,\infty)$, $\sqrt{p^2+1}=\cosh s$, $dp=\cosh s\, ds$. Next, denote $r=\sqrt{\tau^2+x^2}$, $\tau=r\cos \varphi$, $x=r\sin \varphi$, where $\varphi\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. So our integral rewrites as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \exp(-r\cosh(s-i\varphi)).$$
It does not depend on $\varphi$ as may be seen from the rectangular contour (integrals over vertical sides tend to 0).